# Tokbox- don't let the same user publish twice

Tags: opentok, tokbox

If a user is publishing to a tokbox session and for any reason that same user logs in on a different device or re-opens the session in another browser window I want to stop the 2nd one from publishing.

Luckily, on the metadata for the streams, I am saving the user id, so when there is a list of streams it's easy to see if an existing stream belongs to the user that is logged in.

When a publisher gets initialized the following happens:

1. Listen for `session.on("streamCreated")` when this happens, subscribe to new streams
2. Start publishing

The problem is, when the session gets initialized, there is no way to inspect the current streams of the session to see if this user is already publishing. We don't know what the streams are until the `on("streamCreated")` callback fires.

I have a hunch that there is an easy solution that I am missing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you said you save the user ID on the stream metadata, that means when you initialize the Publisher, you set the "name" property. That's a great technique.

My idea is slightly a hack, but its the best I can come up with right now. I would solve this problem by essentially breaking up the subscription of streams into 2 phases:

1. all streams created *before* this client connection
2. all streams created *after*

During #1 I would check each stream's "name" property to see if it belongs to the user at this client connection. If it does, then you know they are entering the session twice and you can set a flag (lets call it `"userRejoining"`. In order to know that #1 is complete, I would set a timer (this is why I call it a hack) for a reasonable amount of time such as 1 second each time a `"streamCreated"` event arrives, and remove the any previous timer.

Then, if the `"userRejoining"` flag is not set, the Publisher is initialized and published to the session.

During #2, you just subscribe to any stream that is created.

The downside is that you've now delayed your user experience of publishing by ~1 second everywhere. In larger group scenarios this could be a deal breaker, but in smaller (1:1) types of sessions this should be acceptable. I hope this explanation is clear, and if not I can try to write some sample code for you.

Comment: Note: each Stream has a "creationTime" property that can be used to figure out if its older than your own connection or not. I don't think its useful here because it doesn't help determine when all the older streams are complete and when you can determine you are in phase 2 (from above).